# Electric field, special relativity, and charged particle

Tags: special-relativity, electric-fields

Given a uniform electric field in the $z$ direction and an observer moving at constant $v$ in the $y$ direction, how you would describe the motion of a charged particle that start at rest in the observer's frame? I'm just looking for qualitative understandings. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A particle that starts at rest in the observer's frame, started with a velocity $v_y$ in the i.e. perpendicular to the field, in the rest-frame. In this direction the particle is not accelerated. But, in the $z$ direction it is accelerated.

As for the observer, since he moves also with velocity $v_y$ the charge has no $v_y$ component in his frame. About the accelerated movement of the particle along the direction $z$, this is perpendicular on the direction of motion of the particle. The distances along the axis z are the same in the two frames, but the time differs. The time interval between the particle reaching two positions along the $z$ axis, is the shortest in the observer frame because there, the two events occur for the same $y$ coordinate.